# need to echo one row in json encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, web

I have this php file and I want to echo one array that ticketnumber is located in it with json encode, in meaning I want to print only one array when isset POST the ticketnumber for this array, but I tried and every time I get error how to slove this problem in addition I used the loop (while) so is it correct for one array?

```
<?php
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB', 'ala');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ('unable to connect');


    if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

        $ticketnumber = $_POST['ticketnumber'];

        $sql = " SELECT * FROM contact WHERE ticketnumber = '$ticketnumber' ";

        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

         $result = array();

        while($get = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            array_push($result,array('ticketnumber' =>$get[0], 'subject' =>$get[1],'response' =>$get[2]));
        }
        if(isset($get)){
            echo json_encode(array("responseticket"=>$result));
        } else {
            echo " error";
        }

}

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, please please please read up on [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), and learn how to change your code so it is not vulnerable to this. Currently your application (and database) is at risk.

Comment: `$ticketnumber = (int)$_POST['ticketnumber'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define variable $get .
I thinks there should be..

```
 if(!empty($result)){
            echo json_encode(array("responseticket"=>$result));
        } else {
            echo " error";
        }
```

Comment: `isset()` does not really work for arrays. Technically `$result` *is set* to `array()` therefore the if statement would return true regardless if `$result` had any values. Something like `if(!empty($result)){...}` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
if(!empty($get)){
 echo json_encode(array("responseticket"=>$result));
} else {
 echo " error";
}
```